# SonarQube: Possibility to jump from WebBrowser Page to Source File

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible ( if it make sense ) to "jump" from a WebBrower page of SonarQube directly to some editor (e.g. Notepad++ ...) or even better to IDE (e.g Visual Studio ... ) in order to make a (very) small correction.

Note: I am trying SonarLint in VS at the present time. This allows you to stay inside the IDE.

Comment: Alt-Tab is your friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, SonarLint is your best friend